# property of rational functions on projective curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, curves

I have a couple of question about the proof of *Lemma* 1.20.5 from Janos Kolloar's Lecture on Resolution of Singularities (page 19):

> *Lemma* 1.20.5 Let $C$ be a reduced, irreducible projective curve (=1D proper $k$-scheme). Then $\sum_{p \in C}e_p(f)=0$ for every rational function $f \in k(C)$.

Remark: $e_p(f)$ is defined on page 17 but for my questions it is not necessary to know what $e_p(f)$ is as it appears later in the proof. Thus consider it as black box. The proof works as follows:

> **Proof.** If $C$ is smooth, then $C \to \mathbb{P}^1$ is everywhere defined. (???) If $C$ is singular, then we only get a rational map $f: C \dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ and this causes problems. Our first step is to reduce to the case where $f:C \to \mathbb{P}^1$ is a morphism.
>
> To do this, let $h$ be a rational function on $C$, which is contained in the local ring of every singular point, i.e. $h \in O_{C,c}$ for every singular $c \in C$. Then $fh^s$ is also in the local ring of every singular point for $s>>1$. Writing $f=(fh^s)/h^s$ and using additivity (1.20.2) (black box), it is enough to prove the assertion for those functions $f$ that are contained in the local ring of every singular point. Such an $f$ can be viewed as a finite morphism $f:C \to \mathbb{P}^1$. Let $C_0:= C \backslash (\text{poles of }f)$ and $C_{\infty}:= C \backslash (\text{zeros of }f)$. Then $k[C_0]$ is a finite and torsion-free $k[f]$-module, and hence free (???) [...]

Questions:

Q_1: Why if $C$ smooth, then $C \to \mathbb{P}^1$ is everywhere defined?

by assumption $f=g/h$ for $g,h \in k[C]$. Why if $C$ smooth then for all $c \in C$ we have $g(c) \neq 0$ or $h(c) \neq 0$?

Q_2: Why $k[C_0]$ is a finite and torsion-free $k[f]$-module?

I think it's torsion free because $C$ integral und thus $k[C]$ integral domain. $C_0$ is also irreducible and rduced thus $k[C_0]$ is also a domain. Thus $k[C_0]$ is torsion-free $k[f]$-module, right? Why is $k[C_0]$ *finite* $k[f]$-module?

Comment: Please take any book on algebraic curves, you'll find the answers. This site if for questions at research level, this is not the place to ask such basic questions.

Comment: @abx: ok, the $Q_2$ meanwhile I solved. Unfortunatelly, I haven't found any lecture on algebraic curves that answers Q_1.(have looked up in Fulton's and Milne's book resp online notes, as well Hartshorne) Honestly at least Q_1 seems not to be a basic thing. Probably you have a concrete book on this topic in mind?

Comment: $Q_1$ is basic but you're looking at it wrong. The condition $g (c) \neq 0$ or $h(c)\neq 0$ is sufficient, but not necessary, for $g/h$ to be well-defined at $c$.

Comment: Try reading Shafarevich, Basic Algebraic Geometry, vol. 1, in particular ch. II, 3.1, Thm. 3. This is a wonderful basic source to precede tackling more advanced material.  Or consult this free curves book, ch. 7.1:
http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf

For better results, please pose any further such queries on stack exchange.

Comment: @WillSawin:hmmm I know that to define a morphism $C \to \mathbb{P}^1$ we need only the ratio $g/h =f \in k(C)$. Possibly it can indeed happen $g(c)=h(c)=0$ but after "killing" common factors" of $g,h$ we can obtain other $g',h'$ with $g'/h'=f$ with $kg'=g,kh'=h$ and $g'(c) \neq 0$ or $h' \neq 0$. Is that what you mean? Suggestively (motivated by naive variety case) we want still well defined "map" $ c \mapsto [g(c):h(c)]$ probably after killing a common factor of $g$ & $h$. What I not understand as in Q_1 stated is why the *smoothness* garantees that this is possible, to find such pair $g,h$.

Comment: Now that you understand what you're looking for, I'm sure you will find the explanation in the sources roy smith mentioned (or one of the ones you've already looked at).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1 is because $C$ is normal, see Corollary 4.1.17 on p.119 of Qing Liu's "Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves".